# Figure reference numbers off by one with cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cleveref

I am having an issue with generating my dissertation using cleveref, where the figure references are references are off by one, such that the reference to figure 1.1 says Fig. 1.0. Anyone have any ideas what would be causing this?

I am using cleveref. A sidenote that may be related, when loading hyperref (which I do before cleveref), I use the option "colorlinks = false", but the links are still colored.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{subfig}       % for figures with multiple subfigures
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}  
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
  \centering
  \tikz \fill [orange] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
  \caption{A figure.}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
A reference to \Cref{fig:1} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a MWE - minimal working example. Otherwise it will be nearly impossible to help you; unless there are fortune tellers among our community...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error you're getting from the MWE you've posted. Which TeX distribution, which versions of the `subfig`, `hypcap`, and `cleveref` packages do you use?

Comment: I'm running texlive 2014.34853-1 from the Arch Linux Extras repository. The dates in the source files are: Hypcap version %% Version: 2011/02/16 v1.11, subfig version date       = "2005/07/05", cleveref v0.19

Answer (score 1):

So in making a MWE, I found the solution. Apparently there is a conflict with `subfig`, `hypcap`, and `cleveref`. I don't need `hypcap` so I was able to just comment it out and everything works.